# How can a <div> extend the length of its <li> parent element?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to web developing, lately I have been practising some basic HTML, CSS, and Javascript(jQuery), I'm reverse engineering some websites in order to practice skills. However, I came across a question that is troubling me already for hours. Here is the question:

I want to make a navbar that looks like the first picture, when you hover over the "Sports" icon, the drop-down list shows. As you can see in the second picture, it is a "div-in-li" HTML (so it is the drop-div that shows), I tried to make the same thing, however, the div always stays the same length as its parent element--li, does anybody know any way to keep the "li" stay its length and make the "div" inside of it expand beyond the limit of the "li" element????
Any solutions are good, doesn't matter it's CSS or Javascript...

The drop-down "div" that contains a "ul" and 3 pictures

[image]

The "div"-in-"li" element

[image]

Comment: Can't say for sure. But I'm guessing they are setting the .sf-mega class to an absolute position. This takes it out of the regular flow of the document and positions it where ever they want. which in this case is right below the main menu and a width of 100%. FYI - they are using the superfish mega menu plugin for Drupal to do this in combination with Bootstrap for creating the columns. So this is not functionality that's been hand coded by the people that built this website. Of course that's not to say you can't hand code a replica of this functionality yourself.

Comment: @Gregg Duncan I think I might just stop thinking this way, I just add one <div> below the entire navbar, then use jQuery to show and hide the <div>, so it will have the same effect like the example, is it a good way in your opinion? Btw, it it better to just use plugins to have such effects than dealing with it in CSS or jQuery? What is the usual way?

Comment: @Gregg Duncan thank you so much. Yes, you guess is right, I looked at the CSS, the .sf-mega class is absolutely positioned and has a width of 100%, I did the same thing, set the width to 100% and absolutely positioned the same class, also set relatively positioned its parent class, however, then the columns in the <div> are pressed together to the left, but NOT beyond left border of the <li> element.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the li element as absolute or float it. Right now, li is positioned as block level and will envelop the div.

Comment: CSS:
#dropdown-div {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute; left: 0;
}

.nav > li {
 position: absolute;
}
#dropdown-div is the ID of the <div>, and also I set the parent <li> element an absolute position, now all the sibling <li> elements are pressed and overlapped together to the left. Also tried to give the <li> a relative position, like I replied to Gregg, the columns I made within the <div> are pressed together but not beyond the left-side border of its parent <li> element...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... Replied you in the last comment but forgot to mention your name. ;)

Comment: @Haiyi Well, yes, absolute positioning will do that, but it's up to you to take care of that and my suggestion does what you want in your original question.